# Summarise time data in a pivot table, into 3 hour blocks

Tags: google-sheets

I've got a bunch of times in a google drive spreadsheet. e.g.:

```
6:25:20
8:24:20
13:49:05
15:11:40
15:16:56
19:12:10
20:31:40
20:48:44
21:00:23
21:34:05
23:33:25
```

(this is just a small example, but in reality there are 100's of times)

I want to group the times into blocks so I can analyse what times are most frequent. Eg. 0-3am, 3-6am, 6-9am etc...

e.g.:

```
0-3am : 0
3-6am : 0
6-9am : 2 
etc..
```

I'm believe the best way to do this is with a Pivot table, which I'm really used to using, but I've tried and cant get this to work, any ideas ?

I've created an example sheet below:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IzNljlrr5RPagJ3HG0QksG4tlj7-QFQhFzLoIkLg1Ps/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1):

This is probably easiest to do with a `query()` formula that counts occurrences by timeslot, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  query( 
    { 
      text(int(A3:A * 24 / 3) * 3, "00") & ":00—" 
      & 
      text(int(A3:A * 24 / 3) * 3 + 2, "00:59"), 
      A3:A 
    }, 
    "select Col1, count(Col2) 
     where Col2 is not null 
     group by Col1 
     label Col1 'timeslot' ", 
    0 
  ) 
)
```

See the [query()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093343) help page.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do something similar would be to add a column into a the data set with the following formula `=FLOOR(A2,"3:00")` which will round the time value to the nearest 3 hour interval. You can then run a pivot table over this rounded data.